# WSL: "tab" character takes up an entire line

Tags: bash, terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux

The "Bash for windows" app is behaving really weirdly whenever any WSL program outputs "\t" to stdout. The first character after the tab is drawn on the *very last* position of the current line. If there are more after that, they get wrapped to the next line. I don't know how or when that happened, because I haven't been using WSL for a long time. Here's an example:

[image]

- Before you ask, yes, it applies to *any* program I call from the terminal.
- I have updated to the latest version of everything, and the problem hasn't fixed itself.
- I would rather not reinstall the whole thing, if possible. At least I want to keep the files I have in the linux filesystem.

So what is this caused by and how do I fix it?

EDIT:

- No special preview builds here, just normal Windows 10 with the update settings on default.
- Version 1903, build 18362.476. Last update was KB4524570.
- Distribution is Ubuntu. I think back when I installed it, Ubuntu was the only one available. Could be wrong though.

Comment: What version of Windows are you using, please specify the exact build, undesirable behavior is often seen on Insider Preview builds.  What WSL distribution are you using?  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: I have tested in latest insider build and it does not occur.

Comment: have you tried `tabs -4`    ?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Apparently "tabs -4" does the trick. Thanks! Please add that as your answer. Can confirm that "tab -0" causes the behavior I described. Is it actually intended that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a standard Bash terminal thing, not just WSL. You can set the tab width used in Bash console using the `tabs` 
command. You can use `tabs -N` to set the tab interval to N characters, `tabs -0` (reset tabs) seems to reproduce the behaviour you describe, and `tabs -8` sets tabs to the standard interval (8 chars). You can use `tabs --help` at the prompt to see the options. If you use the `echo` command with the `-e` option you can see the effect.

The `tabs -0` sets the tab interval to the current console width, but with a quirk with my legacy WSL Ubuntu. I have tried this with WSL, LXterminal on a Raspberry Pi, and a Debian 9 text login.

On the legacy (non-WSL2) standard WSL terminal, as installed by WSL, `tabs -0` seems to set the tab width in the console to some odd (very wide) value, usually bigger than the current terminal window (it's about 231 characters), although if I open a Windows CMD console, and bring up WSL by typing `bash`, or `wsl` then the behaviour is as below.

On the New Windows Terminal (Preview), Raspbian, and Debian, it follows the current window size.

Raspberry Pi LXTerminal

[image]

New Windows Terminal Preview (legacy WSL Ubuntu)

[image]

Debian 9 text console:

[image]